# how can I call an onClick event of an element in html and wait until the click occurs.From another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to develop a website to play cards. In the game loop I need to wait for user's click on an image(which is an element in html) and then decide what to do next. I am using javascript (I have no knowledge on jquery or ajax).How can I make sure a javascript function waits until the user clicks on an image. Thank you in advance.An example with code will be so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript works asynchronously and that means that you cannot block JS process with `while` loop because event like mouse click won't be triggered.

Watch  [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and many things should get clear to you.

For card game you don't really need your own game loop, just add event listener for click to image node, like that:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageID');
img.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // do something, i.e. select clicked card
});
```

Event listeners are everything you need for javascript game. Even if you want to create real time game then all you do is register your physics logic in setTimeout and rendering in requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Firstly I thought there would be some function that may halt the execution for some time until a new click occurs just like scanner or scanf or cin does. :) .Now I understand it doesn't work that way. Adding event listeners and doing some raw codes its all okay now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//implement image click handler

<img src="image1" onclick="jsfunction()" />

<script language="javascript">
    //declare variable to store image is clicked or not
    var imageclicked = false;

    function jsfunction(){
        imageclicked = true;
    }


    function jsWait(){
        if(imageclicked) {

            //include your code here.
            //
            //
            //

            //reset imageclicked variable to false
            imageclicked = false; 
        }

        return false;

    }


    setInterval('jsWait()', 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Buddy, negative vote given by mistake even though answer is accepted as best answer :)